# Uncaught TypeError error in Chrome for multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

On one of the pages I allow user to upload multiple images to upload. Script works fine in Firefox however for sometime it doesn't work on chrome as it give following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')
at uploadComplete (UploadMultipleAlbumImages.js:79:52)
```

[image]

Complete code of this js file

```
var xhr, formData;
var url = baseURL + "admin/albums/UploadImageCropAuto";
var currentLoaderRef, currentTickerRef, fileCount = 0, uploadedFiles = 0, failedFiles = 0, files;
var fileGuids = [], fileNames = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[type='file']").change(function () {
        if (parseInt(this.files.length) > 10) {
            alert("Please select maximum of 10 files.");
        }
        else {
            $('span[id*="Validation"]').html('');
            clearFileUploadFields();
            files = this.files;
            fileCount = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                uploadFile(files[i], url, files[i].name);
            }
            showProgress(this);
            console.log($("#FileGuid").val());
        }
    });
});

function showProgress(fileInput) {
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    currentLoaderRef = $(fileInput).parent().next().children("div.loader");
    currentTickerRef = $(fileInput).parent().next().children("div.checkmark-cover");
    currentLoaderRef.show();
    //$("progress").show();
}

function checkIfFileIsImage(fileType) {
    if (fileType.indexOf("image") == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function uploadFile(file, url, originalFileName) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    formData = new FormData();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);

    //Binding events to the request object
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete.bind(null, originalFileName), false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = getResponseFromServer(xhr);
    formData.append("albumImage", file);
    xhr.send(formData);
}


//Progress event
function uploadProgress(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        //$(".percents").html(" " + ((event.loaded / event.total) * 100).toFixed() + "%");
        $("progress").val(((event.loaded / event.total) * 100));
    }
    else {
        alert("Failed to compute file upload length");
    }
}


function getResponseFromServer(xhr) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

    }
};

//Request complete event
function uploadComplete(originalFileName, event) {
    var response = JSON.parse(event.originalTarget.response);
    fileCount++;
    switch (response.messageType) {
        case "success":
            uploadedFiles++;
            fileGuids.push(response.fileName);
            fileNames.push(originalFileName);
            updateUploadedFilesUl(originalFileName, '', true);
            $("#albumImageFileName").val($("#albumImageFileName").val() + originalFileName + ", ");
            if (fileCount == files.length) {
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                currentLoaderRef.hide();
                currentTickerRef.addClass("opacity0");
                //$("progress").hide();
                $("#FileGuid").val(fileGuids.join('|'));
                $("#FileName").val(fileNames.join('|'));
            }
            break;
        case "largeFile":
            if (fileCount == files.length) {
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                currentLoaderRef.hide();
            }
            updateUploadedFilesUl(originalFileName, response.message, false);
            break;
        case "wrongFileType":
            if (fileCount == files.length) {
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                currentLoaderRef.hide();
            }
            updateUploadedFilesUl(originalFileName, response.message, false);
            break;
        case "exception":
            failedFiles++;
            if (fileCount == files.length) {
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                currentLoaderRef.hide();
                //if (failedFiles == 0)
                //    currentTickerRef.addClass("opacity0");
            }
            updateUploadedFilesUl(originalFileName, response.message, false);
            break;
    }
}

function clearFileUploadFields() {

    $("#albumImageFileName").val('');
    $("#uploadedFilesUL").html('');

    $("#FileGuid").val('');
    $("#FileName").val('');

    fileCount = 0;
    uploadedFiles = 0;
    failedFiles = 0;

    fileGuids = [];
    fileNames = [];
}

function updateUploadedFilesUl(originalFileName, message, isFileUploaded) {
    if (isFileUploaded) {
        $("#uploadedFilesUL").append("<li class='success'>" + originalFileName + "</li>")
    }
    else {
        $("#uploadedFilesUL").append("<li class='failure'>" + originalFileName + " <b>upload failed, error: " + message + "</b></li>")
    }
}

//Request error event
function uploadFailed(event) {
    hideAllLoadersAndCheckMarks();
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#message").html('A problem occured while uploading the image.');
    //$("progress").hide();
}

//Request cancel upload event
function uploadCanceled(event) {
}

function hideAllLoadersAndCheckMarks() {
    $('.loader').hide();
    $('.checkmark-cover').removeClass("opacity0");
}
```

Comment: apparently, `event.originalTarget` is undefined

Comment: (Can you explain why you are still bothering with `XMLHttpRequest` in the first place, when jQuery is in use already? jQuery has an AJAX implementation that is less cumbersome, than dealing with `XMLHttpRequest` yourself ...)

Comment: `event.originalTarget` is a non-standard `event` property available in Firefox only - does *sometime it doesnt work on chrome* mean *it never works on chrome because it's a firefox only property*?

Comment: @CBroe, This is an old website and i have to fix the issue as that developer has left company long back and i am not a JS guy and with KnockOutJS it even harder as we dont have anyone to work on KnockOutJS

Comment: @JaromandaX, You may be 100% correct as i was testing it on FF and issue was report by user who where user Chrome, I wonder why this issue was reported now and not for last 5-6 years. May be developer who coded this didnt knew and even not me till this point. Great Pick. I would appreciate if you can tell me what should i replace it with to support both FF & Chrome..

Comment: @JaromandaX, i change the code to event.Target to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Issues was resolved by replacing the `event.originalTarget.response` with `event.target.response` as `event.originalTarget` is supported only on FireFox browser.

```
//only works in FF event.originalTarget.response
//var response = JSON.parse(event.originalTarget.response);
 var response = JSON.parse(event.target.response);
```

Credit to user @Jaromanda who pointed it out in comments.